# Full width child inside container parent

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a bootstrap *container*, and I need one of the DIVs inside this container to stretch to full screen width:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fullscreen"></div>
</div>
```

I tried with `calc` left but it doesn't work for all screens, sometimes it's bigger, sometimes it's smaller

```css
.fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(134deg, #7FA5FF 0%, #D0E6FE 100%);
}
```

Comment: Only possible to answer if you show all the code.

Comment: this question is confusing. To you actually mean full screen (the entire viewport) which you would solve with `position: fixed; inset: 0;` or do you mean the entire parent which you would solve with `parent { position: relative; } child { position: absolute; inset: 0; }`. Or do you mean a combination of both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a `DIV` inside a page-centered `.container` that extrudes out, touching the window edges, set the width to your child to `100dvw` and set the appropriate `margin-left` using `calc(50% - 50dvw)` like:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: hsla(200 80% 80% / 1);
}

.expanded {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100dvw;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 50dvw);
  background: linear-gradient(134deg, #7FA5FF 0%, #D0E6FE 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  container
  <div class="expanded">
    expanded
  </div>
  container
</div>
```

Comment: My attempts to calculate it correctly or find calculations on the net ended up with creepy formulas and vw instead of dvw and it didn't work accurately

Your version works for me, thanks

Comment: Nice, glad it worked